# Is it ok « It’s not a world where to grow up »

Tags: phrase-request

I have a song that I said something that doesn’t really sounds great grammatically but I wanna know it’s ok or a big mistake

« Everytime I speak it seems too hard, it’s not a world where to grow up »

On the « it’s not a world where to grow up » I’m not sure about the « where to grow up

Comment: It's not a world to grow up in.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because song lyrics are usually not a good source to learn English from.

Comment: You're mixing two structures, the relative clause with "where" and the use of the infinitive to express a goal. You have to choose one or the other: either "where" with a finite verb ("where I want to grow up") or the infinitive with some other adverb or preposition ("a world to grow up in" or "a world to inhabit").